# How to set java.library.path without having to specify it on the command line

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm writing an application that uses the JNI and JDK 9. Normally, to test it, I compile and package my Maven project into a jar:

```
mvn package
```

And then `cd` into the `target` folder and run the program:

```
java -Djava.library.path={path/to/library} -jar myprogram.jar
```

This is fine, but how do I set the library path "permanently" so that I don't have to specify the `-D` option on the command line every single time?

I'm on a Mac (latest version, High Sierra 10.13). I've tried adding `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to my `.bash_profile`.

I've also tried setting it explicitly as a system property in my Java main method, right at the beginning:

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "...");
```

But none of these alternatives work, as I've gotten

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ...
caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
```

no matter what I try. Any suggestions? Does this have to do with the fact that my program is launching as an executable JAR?

Comment: Are you sure your error is a load problem? Looks more like a naming issue to me. Post the entire message and stack trace.

Comment: It's not a naming issue, when I specify the library path on the command line with `-D`, it works. If I don't, I get this message. Nothing changes about the libraries I created.

Comment: Nevertheless you should still post the entire message and stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the library path after the class loader has been created doesn't do much for that class loader.

You can however use a maven plugin to create an executable unit.

The [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/index.html) creates an assembly that contains your jar, its dependencies and scripts to run it that set the class path.

The [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) can create a `jar-with-dependencies` that contains all its dependencies.